# Nucleophilic Aromatic Substitution in ring with 4 Substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

[image]

Does the chlorine still get substituted by OH in this case?

I was also wondering, if it does get substituted, does anything happen between the ethanol substituent and the phenol -OH? I'm suspecting that there might be some kind of ring formation...just a strange feeling.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are right. The tert-butoxide ion being a bulky base will not do an ipso substitution and rather abstract an H+ from -OH and then this -O- will attack the carbon with chlorine to form a ring.